# How to dynamically crop/scale images in a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scaling, crop

I need my site to be able to resize and crop an image based on the viewport on a browser. I've so far managed to dynamically resize it with an imagemap, but can't seem to crop it dynamically. I'd like it to crop and scale simultaneously without distorting an image. The image I'm using is 1920x1080 which is far bigger than most browsers so cropping the edges while scaling would make it appear similar on different browsers.

Comment: How do you plan to use this image? As a background for the site? In a DIV?

Comment: Basically what I've got is a photoshopped image of how I want the site to look which is already divided out into an image map so the "links" are active. I can get it to resize just fine but I left a large border on the right and left side to accommodate those with high resolution screens. For the standard person though I need the edges cropped out.

Answer (score 0):

I use this jQuery plugin quite often. :) 
http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/

Comment: That's very similar to what I've already got figured out, it resizes it, but there's no cropping. I'm using a large image with an html imagemap and can get both of those to resize together, but I'd also like to evenly crop it. There's a rather large area of space on the right and left of the 980px box of info that I'd like to crop out depending on viewport size

Comment: Do you have an example link? I'm having a hard time visualizing what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can already detect the viewport size somehow. You just need the CSS or javascript to crop an image. In that case, I'd recommend this article:

http://cssglobe.com/post/6089/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image

You could

1) Use negative margins.
2) Absolute position the image in a smart way.
3) Use the CSS clip property.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll have to cross that with onResize and throw a bit of math at it, but that should work!